# cohen.d not recognizing numeric values

Tags: r, statistics

I have a sample dataset:

```
Score <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Condition <- c(rep(1,each=5),rep(2,each=3))
Test <- data.frame(Condition,Score)
```

I tried running *cohen.d* from the *effsize* package using the following code:

```
cohen.d(Test,group="Condition")
```

but I obtained this error:

```
Error in cohen.d.default(Test, group = "Condition") : First parameter must be a numeric type
```

even though both column are numeric (I checked both the workspace and used as.numeric).

May I know what did I do wrong? I am aware that someone has solved this issue before ([here's the link](https://github.com/mtorchiano/effsize/issues/41)) but I fail to understand what she did.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Condition` column to factor.

```
Test$Condition <- factor(Test$Condition)
```

There are two ways in which you can apply the function.

1. Using values.

```
library(effsize)

cohen.d(Test$Score, Test$Condition)
```

2. Using formula syntax.

```
cohen.d(Score~Condition, Test)
```